# Move Files Based on Date Stamp in File Name

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell unfortunately, and I have a number of files that I would to like to archive with PowerShell on a monthly basis. Each file has a YYYYMM date stamp in the file name. I'd like to move files that have a date stamp older than 24 months.

Example:

```
file1_201903.txt  
file2_201902.txt  
...  
file3_201703.txt (this should be archived)  
file4_201702.txt (this should be archived)
```

Note that the source files reside in a directory with a number of subfolders. I'd like the script to check all subfolders. The folders do not need to be replicated in the destination.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\source'
$DestDir   = 'C:\destination'
$YearsAgo  = 2

$Then = (Get-Date).AddYears(-$YearsAgo).Date

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir |
    Where-Object {
        $DatePart = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[1]

        $FileDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($DatePart, 'yyyyMMdd', [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

        $FileDate -lt $Then
    } |
    Move-Item -Destination $DestDir
```

Comment: As SO is not a code writing service you will have to do this by yourself. What have you tried already? Please show your code and explain where you stuck or what did not work as expected or what errors did you get.  You might read (again) the following help topics: [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Post updated with formatting and code I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date parts in the filenames do not have a value for the Day. The format should therefore be `yyyyMM`, not `yyyyMMdd`.

Since the format is a sortable string, you do not have to convert to a DateTime object and can go ahead and compare the strings:

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\source'
$DestDir   = 'C:\destination'
$YearsAgo  = -2
$Then      = '{0:yyyyMM}' -f (Get-Date).AddYears($YearsAgo)  # returns a String "201703"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir | ForEach-Object {
    $DatePart = ( $_.BaseName -split '_' )[1]
    # comparing sortable date strings
    if ($DatePart -lt $Then) {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $DestDir
    } 
}
```

If you do want to compare on DateTime objects, this should do it:

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\source'
$DestDir   = 'C:\destination'
$YearsAgo  = -2

$RefDate   = ('{0:yyyyMM}' -f (Get-Date).AddYears($YearsAgo))  # returns a String "201703"
# convert this string into a DateTime object
$Then      = [DateTime]::ParseExact( $RefDate, 'yyyyMM', [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture )

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir | ForEach-Object {
    $DatePart = ( $_.BaseName -split '_' )[1]
    $FileDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact( $DatePart, 'yyyyMM', [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture )
    # comparing DateTime objects
    if ($FileDate -lt $Then) {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $DestDir
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your string comparison code runs without error, but it moves all files, as opposed to only files with filenames older than 2 years. It's also moving the subfolders within source to the destination. It would be fine if they were copied over, as opposed to moved.

Comment: @nate_ak both variants work as expected with your sample files, the error seems to be on your side.

Comment: @Theo Further testing on my end confirms it is working if it doesn't have to consider subfolders in the source directory. I was hoping for the script to look for files within subfolders in the specified source.

Comment: @nate_ak In that case I would suggest that you try adding the `-File -Recurse` switches to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. You may also consider adding `| Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d{6}$' }` before the `ForEach-Object {...}` to get only the files that have a name ending with 6 digits before the extension.

Comment: @Theo thanks for pushing me in the right direction, as I'm completely new to Powershell. Learning on the fly here. Adding `-File `Recurse` definitely helped. However I instead used a substring to calculate the `$DatePart` variable as my filenames will have an inconsistent number of underscores in them. But the datestamp will always be the last 6 characters of the name. So I used  `$DatePart = ( $_.name.substring($_.name.length-10, 6)  )`

Comment: @nate_ak Great, your Substring code will work. Another way would be to use `$DatePart = ( $_.BaseName -split '_' )[-1]`. The `-1` will ensure you get the last part of the split.

Comment: @Theo Oh, good to know. I didn't realize you could go negative with that value.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look that bad actually. ;-) But your `-FilterScript` block in your `Where-Object` needs a little tweak:

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\source'
$DestDir   = 'C:\destination'
$YearsAgo  = -2
$Then = ( Get-Date ).AddYears( $YearsAgo ).Date

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        [datetime]::ParseExact( $(( $_.BaseName -split '_' )[1]), 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture ) -lt $Then
    } |
        Move-Item -Destination $DestDir
```

You could use a little more descriptive way with a `Foreach-Object`. Sometimes that's easier to read/understand/follow:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object{
        $DatePart = ( $_.BaseName -split '_' )[1]
        $FileDate = [datetime]::ParseExact( $DatePart, 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture )
        if ($FileDate -lt $Then) {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestDir
        } 
    }
```

Unfortunately I cannot test at the moment. So try and let me know please. ;-)

Comment: appreciate your assistance, but your code produced the below error. My thought was it was due to the date format in the file names (yyyyMM) not matching the format specified in the `ParseExact` function. I updated the code accordingly, and the script ran with out error.

However, instead of only retrieving files 2 years old or older, it retrieved all files. It also moved the entire folder structure leaving nothing behind. I'd like to retain the folder structure in the source. 

`Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: thanks again for you assistance. This pointed me in the right direction. Theo's code above (with a few of my own minor tweaks) is what I ultimately use for my solution though. And apparently I don't have enough reputation to mark your solution as useful. But it was!

Comment: @nate_ak, don't worry. I'm glad it helped.